# Serverless 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I’m able to follow the documentation to create a simple serverless function, but when I added the `http` listener I keep getting a `502 Bad Gateway` when trying to hit my endpoint.

How can i debug this?

```js
'use strict';

module.exports.hello = async (event, context) => {
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: {
      message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!',
      input: event,
    },
  };
};
```

serverless.yaml

```
service: playing-with-serverless # NOTE: update this with your service name

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          method: get
```

I’ve deployed my function

```sh
 $ sls deploy
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3...
Serverless: Uploading artifacts...
Serverless: Uploading service .zip file to S3 (423 B)...
Serverless: Validating template...
Serverless: Updating Stack...
Serverless: Checking Stack update progress...
..............
Serverless: Stack update finished...
Service Information
service: playing-with-serverless
stage: dev
region: us-east-1
stack: playing-with-serverless-dev
api keys:
  None
endpoints:
  GET - https://1r5mt9wa63.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/hello
functions:
  hello: playing-with-serverless-dev-hello
layers:
  None
Serverless: Removing old service artifacts from S3...
```

cURL

````sh
$ curl --request GET \
  --url https://1r5mt9wa63.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/hello
{"message": "Internal server error"}%```
````

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to stringify `body` in the response object:

```
return {
  statusCode: 200,
  body: JSON.stringify({
    message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!',
    input: event
  })
};
```

[See docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html) specifically `Output Format of a Lambda Function for Proxy Integration`

[Set up an Integration Response in API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-integration-settings-integration-response.html)

Comment: I don't see anything in that section of the docs about having to stringify the body. Can you please quote the exact phrase?

Your suggestion did fix my issue though.

Another question I have is many examples on the net seem to have a 3rd arg `callback`. The serverless generated code example doesn't have this arm. Does serverless abstract the need for this `callback` param and just allow you to return something?

Comment: Docs for integration response is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-integration-settings-integration-response.html). You don't need to use callback in your Lambda because you are using Nodejs 8.1. You can return response or throw exception. But in case of API integration you wouldn't to return response with correct statusCode. You would need to use callback if using Nodejs version less than 8.

Answer (score 1):

There could be an error on your server side code.

Try testing your request on the AWS console. It will point you exactly to the error in your Javascript code if there is one.

[image]